# SQL Gaps in Data- Enroll Date and Disenroll Date 'Active_members'

Tags: mysql, sql

Mainly I am in need of the most practical way to find a list of active members.

Here is the example data set that I am using

```
client    policy holder id   suffix      payor_id    enroll date    disenroll date
A04      GRH130007068       e       GRH0000013000   2009-01-01      0       
A04      GRH130007651       e       GRH0000013000   2010-10-01    2010-10-31
A04      GRH130007887       2       GRH0000013000   2010-10-01    2011-01-31        
A04      GRH130008979       e       GRH0000013000   2009-01-01      0       
A04      GRH130009628       e       GRH0000013000   2006-01-01      0
```

Now the 0's that are in the disenroll date are null values. So I query using this syntax

SELECT * FROM `big_pink`.`EnrollmentHistory`
where Sub_Client_Cd = 'B01' and Policy_Holder_ID = 'BIS355702848'
and Suffix_ID = 'e';

And these are my results

```
CLIENT     PHID            SID          PAYORID    ENROLL DATE        DISENROLL DATE
B01     BIS355702848        e       BIS110990       2003-09-01            2010-01-31            
B01     BIS355702848        e       BIS110990       2010-02-01            2011-06-30    
B01     BIS355702848        e       BIS110990       2011-07-01            2011-09-18            
B01     BIS355702848        e       BIS110990       2011-09-19              0
```

Now what I want to do is make sure that each member was active. So I want these to be singled down into one instance of these claims with a count of 4 respectively. however I need the earliest enroll date and the latest disenroll date....I will later combine this with another table to get a rolling cost per member per month.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  Client, min( Enroll_date) [Registered date], 
        CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM big_pink.EnrollmentHistory  WHERE  Disenroll_Date IS NULL) =  1
        THEN NULL --or whatever value you wish
        ELSE max (Disenroll_Date)
        END [End date], COUNT(*) as n
FROM    big_pink.EnrollmentHistory 
WHERE   Sub_Client_Cd = 'B01' 
AND     Policy_Holder_ID = 'BIS355702848' and Suffix_ID = 'e';
GROUP BY Client
```

Would that give you roughly what you are looking for?

Comment: How would I deal with the null dates though?

Comment: Welp, I never came back. On the off chance you never solved it I've thrown a proper case doodad in the answer

Comment: thanks, I found it and moved on. I have another question though, maybe you can help with... =) thanks again! Cheers!